# Disabling weak Ciphers for Tomcat 5.5.27?

Tags: encryption, weak

Please let me know how can I disable weak Ciphers for Tomcat 5.5.27

Comment: Checkout this [Disabling Weak Ciphers in Tomcat 5](http://java-interview-faqs.blogspot.com/2009/02/tomcat-best-practices-securing-ssl-by.html)

Comment: http://www.techstacks.com/howto/secure-ssl-in-tomcat.html will let you know.

Answer (score 2):

See the `ciphers` attribute in the HTTP connector definition: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Alternatively if you're using APR, see the `SSLCipherSuite` directive as documented in the SSL connector configuration as documented here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/apr.html.

Note that OpenSSL ciphersuite names aren't quite the same as the j2se ciphersuite names. The Java ciphers are documented at: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SunJSSE. For APR, the command `openssl ciphers` will give you a list of all available OpenSSL ciphers on your system.