# evaluating and/or setting the key exchange algorithm in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I have a requirement to secure the TLS channel of a web application running in tomcat 6.

I have limited control of the application itself. I have a requirement to be able to specify and change the modulus size of the key exchange algorithm and cipher algorithm.

I have established that the cipher (ie AES-128 or AES-256) keylength  is determined by the allowed cipher suite. But I do not know how to verify or change the Key Exchange algorithm.

For what it is worth, I am also using client certificate authentication. Certificates are signed with SHA1withRSA.

Many thanks,

Owain

Answer (score 1):

The key exchange algorithm is also specified as part of the cipher suite and is indicated in its name. According to the [TLS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-A.5): "*DHE denotes ephemeral Diffie-Hellman*" (for example). Not all cipher suites of TLS are available in Java (depending on the version of Java and of TLS), but you can check the names in the [Oracle Java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) (if it's the security provider you're using).

Comment: Appoliges for slow response. I have been away for a while. I understand the the algorithm is specified as part of the cipher suite.  I could use EDH with 512 bit modulus, 1024 bit modulus or 2048 bit modules. What I need to know is where this is specified for tomcat?

Comment: The cipher suite configuration is described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323245/how-can-i-disable-weak-ciphers-for-tomcat-5-5-27/323379#323379. It hasn't really changed in more recent version as fas as I know. (You may generally find ServerFault to be a better place to ask this, since it's not really about programming.)